# Как полностью забрать автозаполнение с поля ввода

Tags: html, формы

Браузер Хром. Даже выставив

```
autocomplete=off
```

он заполняет. Как это можно победить?

Comment: У меня не заполняет. Покажите чёткий код примера, в котором всё равно заполняет?

Answer (score 2):

Хром (и некоторые другие браузеры) могут нарушать запрет автокомплита через `autocomplete="off"`

Для гарантированного запрета автокомплита используется трюк. Присвоить аттрибуту autocomplete "невалидное" значение:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

[Пруф](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Disabling_autocompletion)

Если значение не соответствует ни одному из [возможных валидных](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete), то автокомплит работать не будет

Comment: Клёвый хак, не знал.

Comment: он не работает в хроме - http://joxi.ru/L21oewyF8Benbr